# How to access store instance inside prepareAction function of createAction?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

We have two APIs to fetch the data from according to the role of the user.

The `user` information is stored in redux store. And I don't want to pass user as and argument to the service function but needs to access `user` information from store.

I tried to import `store` as `import store from '../store;` in services but it results in `Dependency cycle`.

How can I access the state of store inside services without passing the store or user in arguments and the Dependency cycle?

```js
// actions/product.js

import { createAction } from 'redux-actions';

import * as productService from 'services/products';

const FETCH_PRODUCTS = 'FETCH_PRODUCTS';
const FETCH_PRODUCTS_PENDING = 'FETCH_PRODUCTS_PENDING';
const FETCH_PRODUCTS_REJECTED = 'FETCH_PRODUCTS_REJECTED';
const FETCH_PRODUCTS_FULFILLED = 'FETCH_PRODUCTS_FULFILLED';

const fetchProducts = createAction(FETCH_PRODUCTS, productService.fetchProducts)
```

```js
// services/products.js

export function fetchPractices() {
  let data = [];
  if (user.role == 'admin') {
    data = await axios(fetch from API 1)
  } else {
    data = await axios(fetch from API 2)
  }

  return data;
}
```

```
// component

import { fetchProducts } from 'actions/products';

class Products extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { fetchProducts } = this.props;
    await fetchProducts();
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  products: state.products.products
})

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  fetchPractices,
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Products);
```

Comment: pass user in  your `fetchPractices `. It will work

Comment: yes I know, it will work but I don't want to put it there as I will have to send user in each and every service function